# how would I build a comments box?

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, html, wordpress

I'm interested in creating my own comments box for my website. I want it to be very similar to facebook's commenting system. How difficult would this be and what language is the best for something like this? Also, could someone point me towards some documentation that would help me learn how to do something like this?

Using Rails for the back-end, but could build the box with php preferably using heroku or mysql databases.

Comment: It *all* depends on your back-end infrastructure. If you tell us what you're using for the backend, we'll be able to help

Comment: I'm afraid you have to learn some basics from tutorials. Try this one: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/

Comment: I'm just working front end right now, but i plan to use rails and php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create comments box like Facebook, then you will have to use some server sided scripting technology like PHP, Servlets or any other which does the same thing as these do.
And you will also have to learn DATABASES like mysql, Oracle, Microsoft SQL, etc.
Since these will be used to store comments and retrieve Comments.
My suggestion will be use PHP And MySQL because they are free to use and you can learn these from [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: I have a solid background with SQL and databases, I need to catch up on the development side and learn some php or ruby on rails

Comment: Hey mate, since you have good knowledge about SQL that's really gonna benefit you. And if you want to start with PHP its not that much difficult. But my suggestion would be that go through some OBJECT ORIENTED CONCEPTS first only in brief..... Then surf online for PHP tutorials and you will find plenty of them. Hope that helps you friend at least in some way

Comment: You can see my blog which i have just started a few days ago, about how to learn PHP check it may be this will help you http://easyphpprogramming.wordpress.com